# AVAudioRecorder - how to recover from incoming call

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, avfoundation

I'm trying to achieve something that I thought will be super easy but turns out it's not.

I'm playing with the source code of "react-native-audio" library. But you can assume I'm working natively for the sake of this question.

Here is a [reference for the source code](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/blob/master/ios/AudioRecorderManager.m) I'm playing with.

My goal is simple, I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` to record a meeting (should take 30min approximately). In case of an incoming call in the middle of the recording, I'd like my app to be able to "recover" by doing one of the following options:

1) "pause" the record on "incoming call" and "resume" when app is back to foreground.

2) on incoming call - close the current file, and when app is back to foreground start a new recording (part 2) with a new file.

Obviously option (1) is preferred.

Please note that I'm well aware of using `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` and use it in my experiments with no luck so far, for example:

```
- (void) receiveAudioSessionNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification");
        NSNumber *type = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];

        if ([type isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {
            NSLog(@"*** InterruptionTypeBegan");
            [self pauseRecording];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"*** InterruptionTypeEnded");
            [_recordSession setActive:YES error:nil];            
        }
    }
}
```

Please note I will set up a bounty for this question but the only acceptable answer will be for a real world working code, not something which "should work in theory". Many thanks for the help :)

Comment: This answer show's a third way: 1b) pause on interruption and resume on a new file which you later merge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112943

N.B. this is possible with other APIs.

Comment: Thanks @RhythmicFistman, first this answer is from 2011, hopefully things have changed since then. I don't believe Apple has an open bug for 8 years. And, from my experiments, the incoming call is breaking the current recording file, i.e. there is no way to listen to the recording before the incoming call. This is why I specifically asked for a real world working code

Comment: The wording of Apple's response makes it sound like a design bug, so no code for you! Are you open to other APIs? `AVAudioEngine` and `CoreAudio` can do this.

Comment: Any solution that solve my problem will be fine with me.. I want to be able to record audio and be able to recover from an incoming call

Comment: What are your format options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioFile` as the solution because the code is brief and AVFoundation's interruption handling is [particularly simple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html) (your player/recorder objects are paused, and unpausing reactivates your audio session).

**N.B** `AVAudioFile` doesn't have an explicit close method, instead writing headers and closing the file during `dealloc` a choice which regrettably complicates what would otherwise be a simple API.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) AVAudioEngine *audioEngine;
@property AVAudioFile *outputFile;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error;
    if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error])  {
        NSLog(@"Failed to set session category: %@", error);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioInterruptionHandler:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

    NSURL *outputURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask][0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.aac"];

    __block BOOL outputFileInited = NO;

    self.audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

    AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = self.audioEngine.inputNode;

    [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:512 format:nil block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime * when) {
        NSError *error;

        if (self.outputFile == nil && !outputFileInited) {
            NSDictionary *settings = @{
               AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
               AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(buffer.format.channelCount),
               AVSampleRateKey: @(buffer.format.sampleRate)
            };

            self.outputFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:outputURL settings:settings error:&error];

            if (!self.outputFile) {
                NSLog(@"output file error: %@", error);
                abort();
            }

            outputFileInited = YES;
        }

        if (self.outputFile && ![self.outputFile writeFromBuffer:buffer error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"AVAudioFile write error: %@", error);
        }
    }];

    if (![self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"engine start error: %@", error);
    }

    // To stop recording, nil the outputFile at some point in the future.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(20 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Finished");
         self.outputFile = nil;
    });
}

// https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html
- (void)audioInterruptionHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType type = [info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    switch (type) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:
            NSLog(@"Begin interruption");
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:
            NSLog(@"End interruption");
            // or ignore shouldResume if you're really keen to resume recording
            AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions endOptions = [info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
            if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume == endOptions) {
                NSError *error;
                if (![self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error restarting engine: %@", error);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

N.B. you probably want to enable background audio (and add a `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` string in your Info.plist of course).

Comment: Thank you @Rhythmic, I successfully run and played with your code. It seems like the "stop recording" part is not working as expected, at least for me. When I stop the recording (setting outputFile to "nil") - I can find the audio file in the Documents dir, but not able to play it (I use iTunes File Sharing), it seems like the file is corrupted in some way. 

P.S. I still haven't tested with incoming call, just tried first to get the basic recording flow working

Comment: Unfortunately, `AVAudioFile` doesn't haven't an explicit close method, instead it's closed when it goes out of scope and that's when the m4a header is written out. It sounds like you've introduced another reference to it which is stopping the file closing. Or you're not waiting the 20s for this to happen? Or forget about closing the file and use a headerless format by changing the file suffix to .aac. Or use a more explicit API, like ExtendedAudioFile for your file io.

Comment: p.s. you can get your file from Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators > iPhone > your app > Download Container which gives you the benefit of not needing to use  iTunes or sync your phone

Comment: Hi, I tried to prepare a "stopRecording" method which works like this:
{self.outputFile = nil;} and yes, I had to set a property for outputFile in order to be able to close it (stop recording) from another context. In real-life I don't want to record for exactly 20 seconds

Comment: I just run another test with your original code, I get the same error with the file which seems to be corrupted

Comment: I realise now that using a `__block` variable for an API that does work in its `dealloc` method is a bad idea. I changed my answer to use a property instead. Now the file should actually close. The 20 second recording was just an example, feel free to delete it.

Comment: OK so it's finally working for me when I use the dispatch_after block within the same method I use for start recording. However, if I try to run the same code {self.outputFile = nil;} from a different method - it is not working... any idea why?

Comment: See my previous comment where I changed the answer so that outputFile was a property to avoid this confusion.

Comment: I saw the change you did with the property, still not working when I try to use it in a different method than the one I use to start recording

Comment: That's so weird! Maybe show some code or link to a small project that shows this.

Comment: That code successfully creates a playable file called output-4.m4a but only providing I call the `stopRecording` method. Are you sure you're examining the right file and calling stop?

Comment: Hi, so it turns out I did had a small issue in my code, after I fixed it - it did work finally and I was able to resume recording after incoming call. Please note that in order for the recording to be able to resume while the app is in the background - I had to set "audio" in Background Modes. I super appreciate your help on this one, Many thanks

Comment: Great news, thanks for the bounty! And I hid the part about the background audio mode at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: but how we can recover recording in android devices ? @RhythmicFistman

Comment: I don't know - create a new question about that if there isn't one already